# How can I define templates for multiple controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, view, controller, actioncontroller

I have some nice lean controllers. To further DRY them up, I would like them to share views: so that multiple controllers use the same edit and new views. So I have created a directory of templates called resources which contains a generic `edit` and `new` view.

I have multiple controllers that I would like to share these views (they have their own show templates and forms). Each of these controllers currently inherits from a base `ResourceController`. By default, if any of these controllers is missing a view, Rails will follow the inheritance chain looking for a view, so if my NewsItems controller doesn't have an `edit` template, Rails will automagically look for one in `resources`. However, I would like to remove the need for all these controllers to inherit from a single controller. In my case this adds an extra controller into the inheritance chain which I don't want to do. I would prefer to move the resource introspection shared by the controllers into a mixin.

However, doing so will mean Rails no longer looks in the `resources` view directory for missing templates.

I don't want to render the same 'resources/edit`and`resources/new` templates in every controller, so is there a way of declaring which template to use for which action in a declarative way? Preferably in the mixin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you may be looking for `prepend_view_path`.  So with that you can have e.g. a `MyResources` concern module you include in your controllers:

```
module MyResources
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    prepend_view_path File.join('app', 'views', 'resources')
  end
end
```

Then in any controller that you include `MyResources`, the first path to check for view templates will be `app/views/resources/`, followed by the usual locations.